# React Router V6 Index Route with Nested Routes

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component called Dashboard that renders when the path matches `"/"`.

I want `<Dashboard />` to have nested routes for the left-hand side of the page handled by a nested `<Routes>` inside. The first component in the `<Routes\>` in Dashboard loads fine, but the issue happens when I attempt to render the second component for `"/view-two"`.

I'm pretty sure this is because `"/view-two"` won't match the parent Route `"/"` and therefore `<Dashboard />` isn't even being loaded. When I do `"*"` as the path, it starts to work but my 404 route breaks and doesn't match anymore or has lower priority when visiting a route that shouldn't exist (like `"/fake-page"`).

Does anyone have a way to accomplish this, or is the only way to put `<Dashboard />` in its own path such as `"/home"`?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

App.tsx

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={"*"} element={<PageNotFound />} />  
  //PrivateOutlet is just a wrapper to check if the user is authenticated
  <Route element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
     <Route index element={<DashboardPage />} />
  </Route />
</Routes>
```

DashboardPage.tsx

```
const DashboardPage = () => {
  const path = useLocation();

  console.log(`checking dashboard page`, path.pathname);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<p>View One</p>} />
      <Route path="/view-two" element={<p>View Two</p>} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Comment: I played around with a few things for a day or so when you posted, but also couldn't get anything to work for all routes. I think you need to place view one and two both on subroutes, view one can still be an index route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub-routes should not start with slash ("/") as specified in the docs, here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#nested-routes

So it should be like

```
<Routes>
  <Route index element={<ViewOne />} />
  <Route path="/view-one" element={<ViewOne />} />
  <Route path="/view-two" element={<ViewTwo />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: It shouldn't also have "/" on the paths.